# Export a variable from PHP to shell

Tags: php, shell, export, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a variable that should be accessible from outside PHP. Ideally this should be a local variable, but environment variables are also welcome.

First, I've tried `putenv()`, but this gives no result:

> $ php -r "putenv('PHP_TEST=string');" ; echo $PHP_TEST
>
> $

When i call `getenv()` from the same script — it results in the right 'string' value.
Safe mode is off, but the manual says 'PHP_' prefix is vital with safe=on so I use it just in case :)

Then I try `system()` or `shell_exec()`:

> $ php -r "shell_exec('PHP_TEST=string');" ; echo $PHP_TEST
>
> $ php -r "shell_exec('export PHP_TEST=string');" ; echo $PHP_TEST
>
> $

Is there a workaround? what might be the reason?
I'm using Ubuntu Linux 9.10 "Karmic", but FreeBSD server gives the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to pass some output to a shell variable, you can do it like this:

```
$ testvar=$(php -r 'print "hello"')
$ echo $testvar
hello
```

Showing how export affects things:

```
$ php -r '$a=getenv("testvar"); print $a;'
$ export testvar
$ php -r '$a=getenv("testvar"); print $a;'
hello
```

In these examples, the interactive shell is the parent process and everything else shown is a child (and siblings of each other).

Comment: Thanks! That makes the question clear. But then, how `getopt` (and some other non-builtin programs) manage to export variables to the outer context? (E.g. `getopt` exports `$OPTIND`)

Comment: You're confusing the external `/usr/bin/getopt` which doesn't and can't do that with the builtin `getopts` which does.

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables that are exported are only available in child processes.

So you'll be able to set an environment variable and then spawn a child process. The environment variable will be visible in that child process. However setting it in `php` and then launching a *successive* process (`echo`, in your example above) won't work.

If you set the variable and then spawn/exec a new process, it should be visible in that new process.