# export shell environment variable before running command from PHP CLI script

Tags: php, environment-variables, command-line-interface

I have a script that uses [passthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) to run a command. I need to set some shell environment variables before running this command, otherwise it will fail to find it's libraries.

I've tried the following:

```
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib");
passthru($cmd);
```

Using [putenv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) doesn't appear to propagate to the command I'm running. It fails saying it can't find it libraries. When I run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib` in bash, it works fine.

I also tried the following (in vain):

```
exec("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib");
passthru($cmd);
```

How can I set a shell variable from PHP, that propagates to child processes of my PHP script?

Am I limited to checking if a variable does not exist in the current environment and asking the user to manually set it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002970/export-a-variable-from-php-to-shell

Comment: I've read that question, this looks similar but if you read it, I'm asking how to achieve something different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not 100% familiar with how PHP's exec works, but have you tried: `exec("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib $cmd")`

I know that this works in most shells but I'm not sure how PHP doing things.

EDIT: Assuming this is working, to deal with multiple variables just separate them by a space:

`exec("VAR1=val1 VAR2=val2 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib $cmd")`

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had to space separate multiple environment variables.

Comment: Of course this works; it's too bad there isn't a better approach (or at least not one reported here [yet]).

Answer (score 2):

You could just prepend your variable assignments to $cmd.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat doit.php 
<?php

$cmd='echo "output=$FOO/$BAR"';

$cmd="FOO=bar;BAR=baz;" . $cmd;

print ">> $cmd\n";
passthru($cmd);

[ghoti@pc ~]$ php doit.php 
>> FOO=bar;BAR=baz;echo "output=$FOO/$BAR"
output=bar/baz
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things come to mind. One is for $cmd to be a script that includes the environment variable setup before running the actual program.

Another thought is this: I know you can define a variable and run a program on the same line, such as:

```
DISPLAY=host:0.0 xclock
```

but I don't know if that work in the context of `passthru`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Bash.27s_quick_assignment_and_inheritance_trick

Comment: $cmd is actually a command to run an ant build file, this script wraps construction of that command.