# PHP exec() running as if in the wrong environment

Tags: php, exec, environment

I had this bug at work today - won't be able to test it until I get back there after the weekend but thought someone might know the answer offhand.

I have two scripts, file_1.php and file_2.php.  They are located in the same folder within my codebase.  Said codebase includes many many files, including a global 'header' file which calls several other files and pretty much sets up any file to run on our environment.

What I would like to do is run file_2.php from within a `shell_exec()` or `exec()` from file_1.php.  However, when I do this, file_2.php doesn't recognize the file 'header.php' unless provided with the absolute filepath, and even when it is provided, not all calls to other files (there are several `include`s, `require`s, etc, in header.php) succeed - though some do.

At the point where I left it, the latest file that was not included had been correctly identified by providing the complete filepath to it as well (as opposed to only the relative one), but I received an 'unidentified function' error on `apache_note()`, which is a function bundled with PHP.

I'm running these from the command line, and when I run only test_2.php alone it works fine, but when it is accessed by way of `exec()` from file_2.php, this is my situation.  Is there something I'm missing about `exec()`?  Is there a way to run the second file as if in exactly the same environment as the first one?  (I tried `putenv()` with no success, but perhaps there's a trick involving that?

Help or ideas greatly appreciated, though I won't be able to check for a couple of days.  Happy Thanksgiving to all ;)

Comment: Have you tried `require()`'ing header.php using path preceded with `__DIR__`?

Comment: I was using our SYSTEM_BASEDIR global variable, passed in from file_1.php, which I believe uses that.  I'll double check though, thanks for the idea

Comment: `shell_exec()` and similar may run from the current user's home directory, that would be my wild guess.

Comment: Going to try this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636605/export-shell-environment-variable-before-running-command-from-php-cli-script